# ternary condition operator issue in C++

Tags: c++, integer, ternary-operator

**My goal :** Enter two integers and sum all the integers from the small number to the big number.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int v1, v2;
    std::cout << "Enter two integers: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;

    int big, small;
    big = v1 > v2 ? v1, small = v2 : v2, small = v1;

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = small; i <= big; i++)
        sum += i;
    std::cout << "The sum is " << sum << std::endl;

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of using if statement, I want to test ternary condition operator.

When v1 is smaller than or equals v2, like

```
Enter two integers: 
1
5
The sum is 15
```

The result works fine.

But when v1 > v2, the result is wrong.

```
Enter two integers: 
5
1
The sum is 0
```

I can't think of why. 
Can someone explain , please?

Comment: Please don't abuse the conditional expression. It is code like this that gives it a reputation as incomprehensible.

Comment: `std::tie(small, big) = std::minmax(v1, v2);`, or even `auto [small, big] = std::minmax(v1, v2);`.

Comment: `v1 > v2 ? v1, small = v2 : v2, small = v1` is just unreadable code. It's hard to see the intended structure (ternary operator) through all the tokens, hard to verify that the compiler parses it that way (it actually doesn't!), and even harder to verify that it would perform the intended swapping. Programming is not about who can write the most clever looking code but who can communicate most effectively through code (which this is the opposite of).

Comment: Note that sum of arithmetic series can be calculated in constant time without using any loop, using the magic of maths.

Comment: The problem isn't with the ternary operator.   It is with your MISUSE of multiple operators in one expression.   You haven't accounted for operator precedence or associativity correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to swap the terms on each side of the comma operator because `big` will be assigned the last one on the list. You also need to add parentheses in order to make it evaluate correctly:

```
big = (v1 > v2) ? (small = v2, v1) : (small = v1, v2);
```

See the explanation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other):

> In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression `E1` is evaluated, its
>   result is discarded [...] The type, value, and value category of the result of the comma expression are exactly the type, value, and value category of the second operand, `E2`

---

Also, if you want it to be short and readable, you could consider this instead:

```
std::cin >> big >> small;
if (small > big)
    std::swap(big, small);
```

Comment: You need parentheses. The last comma is not a sub-expression of the conditional. Other way around in fact.

Comment: It worked for me without the parentheses, but adding them is a good idea anyway. It makes it much more readable in my opinion, and perhaps it just worked for me by chance.

Comment: Don't know how you checked, but it was buggy nonetheless. The warning [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GOWTNa5eZAvCQuaf) is indicative of how things are parsed.

Comment: _It worked for me without the parentheses_ This would mean your compiler is broken. ;-) According to [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the comma operator has the highest precedence no. at all, meaning it binds least. I.e. `big = v1 > v2 ? small = v2, v1 : small = v1, v2;` is equal with `big = (v1 > v2 ? small = v2, v1 : small = v1), v2;` i.e. stores always `v2` into `big` regardless what the condition evaluates to. This is probably not what you intended.

Comment: Yes, you're right, with different numbers I now see that it's definitely not working without parentheses. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
big = v1 > v2 ? v1, small = v2 : v2, small = v1;
```

This doesn't do what you expect.
When using the comma operator `,` to separate a number of expressions, the resulting expression gets the value of the last of those expressions. So in your case, if `v1 > v2`, `big` is assigned the value of:

```
 v1, small = v2
```

which is the value of `small = v2`, which becomes `v2` instead of `v1` as you intended. So you end up assigning both numbers the same value when `v1 > v2`!

You could use separate statements:

```
big = v1 > v2 ? v1 : v2;
small = v1 < v2 ? v1 : v2;
```